# Estimates for Sum of Prime Factors and Number of Prime Factors

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, divisor-sum

Given a positive integer $n$, are there estimates for the **sum of distinct prime factors** of $n$ and for the **number of distinct prime factors** of $n$ (sometimes denoted $\omega(n)$)? I'm not interested in asymptotics, but it would be useful to have some inequalities for each $n$.

1. number of distinct prime factors: http://oeis.org/A001221
2. sum of distinct prime factors: http://oeis.org/A008472

Comment: If you exclude prime , then there is a formula I know for the sum and number of factors of n

Comment: Does your formula count the distinct factors or does it include multiplicities?

Comment: It counts distinct, for n=4, it gives the answer 3 , because 1,2,4 are factors of 4 , thats why I was saying to exclude prime@TheSubstitute

Comment: That doesn't fully resolve my question, but I can try to obtain my needed estimates from those quantities. Can you post those here?

Comment: That is normal combinatorics, if a number $n$ is written in form of $$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_n^{a_n}$$ then number of factors of $n=(a_1+1).(a_2+1).(a_3+1)....(a_n+1)$ for example if $n=2^3×3^4$ then factors of $n=(3+1)(4+1)=20$

Comment: Do you want the formula for sum too?@TheSubstitute ? But my formula count all the factors, not only prime ones !!

Comment: If you have something other than the Mobius function, please share. Got it.

Comment: As for the sum of distinct prime factors, they behave in irregular way but we can bound them between $\ln n \ln \ln n$ and $n$ and these bound are strict since if $n$ is prime the upper bound hold exactly and if $n$ is product of consecutive primes then there sum is very close to $\ln n \ln \ln n$.